# How to be more efficient when using the touchpad?

Tags: windows-8, mouse, touchpad

Is there any more efficient way to use the touchpad on Windows 8? Special gestures or some good hand position/pose when you are using it? I find the touchpad limits my efficiency since I can't move the cursor fast enough or with enough accuracy... Is software that would add new gestures or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few I think are [supported by windows 8](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-8-tip-use-trackpad-multi-touch-gestures) by default, like pinch to zoom, two finger scroll, etc. Your trackpad manufacturer could also have added some more gestures, so to know what else there is, it might be a good idea to check on your manufacturers website for more gestures.

Personally I use keyboard shortcuts in combination with my trackpad to optimize my productivity when I do not have a mouse handy.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just wanted to know if there were some secret to using the trackpad more effectively, I see many people able to work with it very efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found two-finger tapping for right click and two-finger dragging for scrolling to be very helpful. You may also want to see if you can enable cursor momentum. Some people hate it but I found it very useful when I need to use the touch pad.

What is the make/model of the computer? If you are using the default Windows drivers, see if you can find drivers for your particular touch pad from the computer or device manufacturer. Device-specific drivers will give you more customization options.